# how to write sub query child query with multiple row parent query single row return

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The following query produces some errors:

```
$sub = '( SELECT mulitple.* FROM timezoneabbreviation AS mulitple
      WHERE single.gmtoffset = mulitple.gmtoffset) AS sametimezone';
$query = "SELECT $sub,single.* FROM timezoneabbreviation AS single 
         WHERE full_name='".$full_name."' ";
return $this->db->query($query)->row();
```

I want to write a query with a subquery in the same table with where condition main query produces single row but sub query produces multiple rows.

Comment: What is your data structure? What is the error (programming 101: The error messages contain a wealth of information, learn to read them and google the error itself).

Comment: query produce this error  Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: It will be more easier if you check your query by executing it in mysql....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
$query = "SELECT mulitple.*, single.*
          FROM timezoneabbreviation AS single
          INNER JOIN timezoneabbreviation AS mulitple
              ON mulitple.gmtoffset = single.gmtoffset
          WHERE single.full_name='".$full_name."'";
```

Comment: this query produce error "Operand should contain 1 column(s) "

Comment: Can you show yout tables schemas? Which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: show this result in single row but i want a multiple row from innerjoin table stdClass Object ( [abb_id] => 3 [abbreviation] => ACDT [full_name] => Australian Central Daylight Time [location] => Australia [hours] => +10:30 hours [gmtoffset] => 37800 [timezone_offset] => 10.5 )